# iOS Core Data to Android SQLite Mapping

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a fairly simple question to ask as I am new to iOS programming, I have an iOS app developed by some developer and uses Core data as database, now what I would like to understand is that, I have to make the same app on Android as well, so how will I map the core data from the iOS App to SQLite for Android, I have complete code for iOS App, I am really confused as I don't have documentation on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Find path to your application documents using below code. Add this method in `AppDelegate` class and call from any of the application life cycle methods.

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
  - (void)findDocumentsDirectory
  {
     NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory  inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
  }
```

Go to the path and find .sqlite file created by core data for your application. Copy the same .sqlite file and paste it to your Android application folder. On `SqliteHelper` class pass copied sqlite file path. It should work as expected.